# Meaning difference between two sentences

Tags: sentence-meaning

Movies, paintings and music are all **devices** of interpretation.

Movies, paintings and music are all **subject** to interpretation.

Do both these sentences mean the same thing?
Are both of them grammatically correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The sentences are grammatically correct, although the phrase "devices of interpretation" is not a common one.

However, the sentences are not identical. The first states that movies, paintings and music are used as devices to interpret something else, whereas the second states that one can interpret movies, paintings and music subjectively.

In other words, the first and second sentences refer to movies, paintings and music as the output and the input, respectively, of some interpretive process.